# Combining two query sets across a unique key

Tags: python, django

I have two query sets that I'd like to combine with the 'month' being the unique key to combine on.

**Query Set 1 (Impressions) **

`[{'events': 1503, 'month': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 1, 0, 0)}, {'events': 32747, 'month': datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 1, 0, 0)}]`

**Query Set 2 (Clicks) **

`[{'events': 163, 'month': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 1, 0, 0)}, {'events': 4184, 'month': datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 1, 0, 0)}, {'events': 5049, 'month': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 1, 0, 0)}, {'events': 592, 'month': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 1, 0, 0)}]`
`

Is it possible to combine them such that the output would look like this?

`[{'clicks': 163, 'impressions': 1503, 'month': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 1, 0, 0)}, {'clicks': 4184, 'impressions':32747, 'month': datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 1, 0, 0)}, {'events': 5049, 'month': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 1, 0, 0)}, {'events': 592, 'month': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 1, 0, 0)}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code fragment

```
clicks = list(clicks.values())
impressions = list(impressions.values())
res = {i['month'] : {'month': i['month']} for i in clicks + impressions}
for i in clicks:
    res[i['month']].update({'clicks': i['events']})
for i in impressions:
    res[i['month']].update({'impressions': i['events']})
res = list(dict.values())
```

Comment: Thanks I get this though:`unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'ValuesQuerySet' and 'ValuesQuerySet'` in the first line.

Comment: @natab Can you please mention the type of the clicks and impressions object in question as by standard `[` and `]` are the standard convention used for `list` type.

Comment: They are both `<class 'django.db.models.query.ValuesQuerySet'>`

Comment: @natab I added the conversion code. I hope it should work now.

Comment: I ended up doing `merged_results = list(chain(clicks, impressions))` and then did `res = {i['month'] : {'month': i['month']} for i in merged_results}`, the rest worked great. Thanks a lot for the help!